# How to configure additional classpath in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, external, q

I want to make a standalone web application. I have some problems with SpringBoot.

My application is one jar file from SpringBoot.

But my application was usually needed jdbc driver jar. I want to exclude the jdbc driver jar for my application and read the library jar from the lib folder.

But SpringBoot lib folder is `BOOT-INF/lib` is `final static`. So, I want to add external classpath (lib) for the jdbc driver jar.

How to configure additional classpath in SpringBoot. Is it available?

Answer (score 33):

You can use the `loader.path` parameter to define a location for an external lib folder. All jars under this folder will be added to the classpath. For example, if you'd like to define `C:\extLib` as your external lib folder, you can do the following:

```
java -Dloader.path=/C:/extLib/ -jar aapName.jar
```

For this to work, you need to use the PropertiesLauncher. There are two ways to do that:

**Option 1**

Update the project pom.xml and add the following tag:

```
<configuration>  <!-- added -->
  <layout>ZIP</layout> <!-- to use PropertiesLauncher -->
</configuration>
```

Effective build tag, the post-update looks like below:

```
<build> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>  <!-- added -->
                <layout>ZIP</layout> <!-- to use PropertiesLauncher -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Option 2**

Use the PropertiesLauncher when launching the application from the commandline:

```
java -cp aapName.jar -Dloader.path=/C:/extLib/ org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

References:
[How to add jars to SpringBoot classpath with jarlauncher](https://mash213.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/hack-how-2-add-jars-2-springboot-classpath-with-jarlauncher/)

Comment: Does this work with properties or just jars?

Answer (score 14):

You may refer this below link from spring boot:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features

> You can use the loader.path property to define a lib folder location

Comment: Thank yor for your answer. But it is now working. My application : /dev/myapp.jar, External library : /dev/lib/ojdbc6.jar. Set the "loader.path",but library was not loaded.

Comment: @FIGHTINGMAMORU, your comment is confusing. It is mentioned `working` first and later said `library was not loaded`. Have you got it working?

Comment: I think he meant 'not' working instead of 'now' working.  I'm having a similar issue with standalone spring boot jars.  It doesn't seem to be loading a single jar with loader.path.  Does it have to be a directory?  I don't necessarily want to load everything in the folder with my dependency jar

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was needed " quote to find the external lib folder on windows platform

```
java -cp ScoreExtractionApp.jar -Dloader.path="lib" -Dloader.main=com.sample.score.ScoreExtraction.ScoreExtractionApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure class path in maven using maven jar plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
       <manifest>
           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
       </manifest>
    </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```