# Adding external jars in classpath to an executable WAR file

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot executable WAR file which I launch using java -jar . Now I want to add the flexibility of having it reference JAR files outside of WAR file so as to enable customization of code.
So e.g. I want to have to flexibility of having a jar being present in d:\mylib\my.jar and reference the classes in  my.jar from code within the WAR file.

Is this possible?
If yes, how?

I tried adding Class-Path and even editing the spring-boot-lib path in manifest.mf but no use.

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499548/how-to-configure-additional-classpath-in-springboot ? Maybe it works for you.

Comment: I tried this earlier. The problem is I have a WAR file which is not loaded by PropertiesLauncher